# How do I traverse a Bootstrap tabbed navigation menu with nested dropdown using prev and next button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, navigation

I've a template that has tabbed navigation with a nested dropdown menu. The previous and next buttons should provide secondary navigation through each of the tabs. The buttons work until they need to go through the pages in the dropdown navigation. If you use the Next button to advance to a lecture, all of the pages/lectures in the dropdown will be displayed below the buttons.

I'm not sure of the best way to approach writing out the if/else piece in the js. Not sure if it's better to look at if/else based on what I have so far or start from scratch. I need help with figuring out how to get the script to go forwards and backwards through the entire list used for navigation.

```
     $('.btnNext').click(function () {
          $('.nav-tabs > .nav-item > .active').parent().next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
     });

     $('.btnPrevious').click(function () {
         $('.nav-tabs > .nav-item > .active').parent().prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
     });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<body>

<nav role="navigation"> 
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link active" id="tab1" data-toggle="tab" href="#page1" role="tab" >Welcome</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="#page2" id="tab2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab"  class="nav-link">Activities</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
               <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Lectures</a>
               <div class="dropdown-menu">
                     <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" id="tab3" href="#page3">Lecture 1</a>
                     <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" id="tab4" href="#page4">Lecture 2</a>
                     <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" id="tab5" href="#page5">Lecture 3</a>
              </div> 
          </li>

     </ul>
</nav>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">     
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="page1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="overview-tab">
     <h2>Overview</h2>
     <p>Page 1.  </p>

    <div>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext nextRight">Next <em class="fas fa-chevron-right"></em></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="page2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="activities-tab">
     <h2>Activities</h2>
      Page 2. 
          <div class="alert alert-info fade in">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            <p class="text-center">If you have questions regarding any of these activities, make sure to post those questions in the <strong>Open Forum</strong>.</p>
          </div>
    <div>
     <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext nextRight">Next <em class="fas fa-chevron-right"></em></a>
     <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"> <em class="fas fa-chevron-left"></em> Previous</a>
    </div>     
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="page3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="page3-tab">
     <h2>Lecture 1</h2>
     <p>Page 3.</p>

    <div>
     <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext nextRight">Next <em class="fas fa-chevron-right"></em></a>
     <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"> <em class="fas fa-chevron-left"></em> Previous</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="page4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="page4-tab">
     <h2>Lecture 2</h2>
     <p>Page 4. </p>
    <div>
     <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext nextRight">Next <em class="fas fa-chevron-right"></em></a>
     <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"> <em class="fas fa-chevron-left"></em> Previous</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="page5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="page5-tab">
     <h2>Lecture 3</h2>
     <p>Page 5. </p>
         <div>
     <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"><em class="fas fa-chevron-left"></em> Previous</a>

    </div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working **demo** using [`tab('show')`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#tabshow) instead of `trigger('click')`

```js
$('.btnNext').click(function() {
  if (!$('[data-toggle="tab"].active').next('[data-toggle="tab"]').first().tab('show').length)
    $('[data-toggle="tab"].active').parents('li').nextAll().find('[data-toggle="tab"]').first().tab('show')
});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function() {
  if (!$('[data-toggle="tab"].active').prev('[data-toggle="tab"]').first().tab('show').length)
    $('[data-toggle="tab"].active').parents('li').prevAll().find('[data-toggle="tab"]').last().tab('show')
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="tab1" data-toggle="tab" href="#page1" role="tab">Welcome</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#page2" id="tab2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="nav-link">Activities</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Lectures</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" id="tab3" href="#page3">Lecture 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" id="tab4" href="#page4">Lecture 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" id="tab5" href="#page5">Lecture 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="page1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="overview-tab">
    <h2>Overview</h2>
    <p>Page 1. </p>

    <div>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext nextRight">Next <em class="fas fa-chevron-right"></em></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="activities-tab">
    <h2>Activities</h2>
    Page 2.
    <div class="alert alert-info fade in">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext nextRight">Next <em class="fas fa-chevron-right"></em></a>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"> <em class="fas fa-chevron-left"></em> Previous</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="page3-tab">
    <h2>Lecture 1</h2>
    <p>Page 3.</p>

    <div>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext nextRight">Next <em class="fas fa-chevron-right"></em></a>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"> <em class="fas fa-chevron-left"></em> Previous</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="page4-tab">
    <h2>Lecture 2</h2>
    <p>Page 4. </p>
    <div>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext nextRight">Next <em class="fas fa-chevron-right"></em></a>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"> <em class="fas fa-chevron-left"></em> Previous</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="page5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="page5-tab">
    <h2>Lecture 3</h2>
    <p>Page 5. </p>
    <div>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious"><em class="fas fa-chevron-left"></em> Previous</a>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```